# Can Mathematica solve $|-x\cdot\exp(-0.5x^2/b^2)/b^2|<0.01$?

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I've tried the following

```
eq = Abs[-x*Exp[-0.5*x^2/(t^2)]/(t^2)]
Reduce[eq < 0.01 && x > 0 && t > 0, {x, t}, Reals]
```

But *Mathematica* complains:

```
Reduce::inex: Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Reduce require exact input, providing Reduce with an exact version of the system may help
```

Comment: Try to take a look at this: `RegionPlot[ eq < 1/100, {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, 100}]`

Comment: Thx for that hint, you're right...Its basically supposed to be the derivative of the gaussian function.EDIT: I know about RegionPlot but is there a way to get an analytical expression or how can I check if this is solvable at all?

Comment: It can solve `eq==1/100` (also replace `0.5` by `1/2`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we want exact values we should work with them from scratch.

```
eq[t_, x_] := Abs[-x Exp[-1/2 x^2/(t^2)]/(t^2)]
```

The boundary of the set of our interest can be described when we fix one of the two variables, therefore we can define e.g.:

```
    r[t_] := Reduce[ eq[t, x] < 1/100 && t > 0 && x > 0, {x}]
```

We need the function `r` because in general *Mathematica* doesn't work well when two independent variables are involved in a transcendental function.

```
r[46]
```

> ```
> 0 < x < Root[{529 E^(#1^2/4232) - 25 #1 &, 24.3393586725922949851}] ||
>     x > Root[{529 E^(#1^2/4232) - 25 #1 &, 71.980168424194312044}]
> ```

This means that the inequality is satisfied for `t == 46` when
 `x < Root[{529 E^(#1^2/4232) - 25 #1 &, 24.3393586725922949851}` or 
 `x > Root[{529 E^(#1^2/4232) - 25 #1 &, 71.980168424194312044}]`.  `Root` is  a symbolic representation of an exact solution, numerically approximate values are `x < 24.3393 || x > 71.9801`.

Let's visualize the subset of the solution space for `t == 51`

```
 Show[{ RegionPlot[eq[t, x] < 1/100, {t, 0, 80}, {x, 0, 80}] // Quiet, 
        Graphics[{Thick, Orange, Line[{{51, 0}, {51, 31.461}}], 
                                 Line[{{51, 73.521}, {51, 80}}]}]}]
```

[image]

The blue region represents the solution space, while the orange lines are its subset for `t == 51`.